# Wix Minor Upgrade patch doesn't change version when created using Purely Wix (v3.10.3.3007)

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, msi-patch

1) I created a patch using the following wix tutorial (using PCP)
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/patch_building.html

The tutorial uses same product.wxs (with 1.0.0 version) for both the MSIs generation, but I used product1.0.wxs (with 1.0.0) and product1.1.wxs (with 1.1.0), so that we will get one MSI with 1.0.0 version and another with 1.1.0 version.

The patch was successfully installed and changed the version from 1.0 to 1.1 in 'Programs and Features' (I could also see the patch in 'Installed Updates')

2) Now, I created a patch using the following wix tutorial (using Purely Wix)
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html

In this tutorial also, same version (1.0.0) was used in product.wxs for creation of both 1.0\product.msi and 1.1\product.msi. However, I used two separate .wxs files - one with Version="1.0.0" (product1.0.wxs) and another with Version="1.1.0" (product1.1.wxs) - just like previously.

```
candle.exe -dVersion=1.0 product1.0.wxs
light.exe product1.0.wixobj -out 1.0\product.msi
candle.exe -dVersion=1.1 product1.1.wxs
light.exe product1.1.wixobj -out 1.1\product.msi
torch.exe -p -xi 1.0\product.wixpdb 1.1\product.wixpdb -out patch\diff.wixmst
candle.exe patch.wxs
light.exe patch.wixobj -out patch\patch.wixmsp
pyro.exe patch\patch.wixmsp -out patch\patch.msp -t RTM patch\diff.wixmst
```

When I install the patch.msp obtained above, it can be seen in 'Installed Updates', but the product version doesn't change from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 in 'Programs and Features'.

After comparing the 2 Patch install logs, I understood that the patch obtained by the Purely Wix method is being considered as a 'Small Update' patch.

I am struggling to find out why the patch is created as a 'Small Update' patch instead of a 'Minor Update' patch, though I changed the Version.

Can anyone familiar with this kindly help?

Note: Kindly dont ask me to do a Major Upgrade. I am looking only for Minor Upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including 
`<PropertyRef Id="ProductVersion"/>` in

```
<PatchFamily/>
```

resolved the issue.

Thanks to my friend who helped me in finding this.